# c# set outlook mailbox as mailitem.sender

Tags: c#, outlook, mailitem

how to set mailitem.sender as account's mailbox..

each account could have multiple mailboxes. i am able to access all smtp accounts but not able to set their mailboxes as mailitem.sender

outlook mailboxes we can access using 
Outlook.Session.Folders

Answer (score 0):

The [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class allows to set an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent. For example:

```
 Sub SendUsingAccount() 
  Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
  For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
    Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
    oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
    oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
    oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
    oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
    oMail.Send 
   End If 
  Next 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Hi i tried it, it sending through my primary email account not its mailbox's one... suppose i have primary email account abc@www.com and mail box added to it like xyz@www.com. xyz@www.com i can access through .session. folders but not as part of sessino.accounts

Comment: Try to use the [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862145.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property which indicates the display name for the intended sender of the mail message. It works only with Exchange and delegated permissions.